# how to extract the first parameter from a line containing a particular string pattern

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a file named mail_status.txt The content of the file is as follows.

```
1~auth_flag~
2~download_flag~
3~copy_flag~
4~auth_flag~
5~auth_flag~
6~copy_flag~
```

I want to perform some operation on this file so that at the end I should be getting three variables  and their respective values should be as follows:

```
auth_flag_ids="1,4,5"
download_flag_ids="2"
copy_flag_ids="3,6"
```

I am quite new to this language. Please let me know if some more details are required on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to generate `bash` variables based on the file content,
please try the following:

```
# read the file and extract information line by line
declare -A hash                     # delcare hash as an associative array
while IFS= read -r line; do
    key="${line#*~}"                # convert "1~auth_flag~" to "auth_flag~"
    key="${key%~*}_ids"             # convert "auth_flag~" to "auth_flag_ids"
    hash[$key]+="${line%%~*},"      # append the value to the hash
done < "mail_status.txt"

# iterate over the hash to create variables
for r in "${!hash[@]}"; do          # r is assigned to "auth_flag_ids", "download_flag_ids" and "copy_flag_ids" in tern
    printf -v "$r" "%s" "${hash[$r]%,}"  # create a variable named "$r" and assign it to the hash value by trimming the trailing comma off
done

# check the result
printf "%s=\"%s\"\n" "auth_flag_ids" "$auth_flag_ids"
printf "%s=\"%s\"\n" "download_flag_ids" "$download_flag_ids"
printf "%s=\"%s\"\n" "copy_flag_ids" "$copy_flag_ids"
```

- First it reads the lines of the file and extracts the variable name
  and the value line by line. They are stored in an associative array `hash`.
- Next it iterates over the keys of `hash` to create variables whose names are
  "auth_flag_ids", "download_flag_ids" and "copy_flag_ids".
- `printf -v var` creates a variable `var`. This mechanism is useful to cause an
  indirect reference to a variable.

I'm not going to explain in detail about the `bash` specific notations
such as `${parameter#word}`, `${parameter%%word}` or `${!name[@]}`.
You can easily find the references and well-explained documents including
the bash man page.

Hope this helps.